# wxPython Window ID

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to write a photo frame app utilizing wxPython.  To view videos as well as photos I started off using wx.media but found the gstreamer backend to insufficient.  So I turned to mplayerctrl and ported it over to Python3/Phoenix.  The thing I've been struggling with to get it working is programmatically retrieving the window id to pass into mplayer so that the  video plays inside the frame.  I've verified that this works if I get the window id from xwininfo however if I use GetHandle() it returns 0 and if I use GetGtkWidget() it returns a value but that value doesn't correspond to the window id.  The stock version of mplayerctrl used self.Handle.
https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Window.html

I'm looking for a solution that works in Linux but will hopefully be portable to other platforms.  Also ideally this solution would be wxPython/Python native.

Thanks

Comment: self.panel1.GetHandle() works for both gstreamer1.0 and vlc on linux using wxpython classic. I see no reason why that should have changed.

Comment: Except that it has

Comment: see if this helps http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/GetHandle-example-td5726968.html

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I know that the results from xwininfo provides the appropriate window ID to for mplayer to use however I still can't get that number out of wxPython.  Thanks for the lead though.

Comment: Using `xwininfo -int -tree` or `xwininfo -int -children` should show you that one of the children has the same `Id` as `self.panel1.GetHandle()` (or whatever). It certainly does on my box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding wxpython in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798043/adding-wxpython-in-pygame)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are attempting to set the `handle` too soon.
I suspect that you are initiating the `handle` as part of your initialisation routine. I have found that you should wait until you have selected a video to play and use the `self.xxxxx.GetHandle()` at that point i.e. you perform that function for each item that you ask the player to play.
I have tested this with python 3.5.2 wxpython 4.0.02b Linux Mint 18.2 and using `Vlc`.
It seems to be that the `MainLoop` must have started before `GetHandle` will return a valid value.